# background-size: cover leaves padding on sides, only in one case. Chrome bug?

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-size

Heyas,

Running into a weird problem where on a bunch of templated pages, only one of the pages shows this white sliver on the left of a hero banner. The banner is using a background image with size: cover, and positioned at center/center. If I remove all the content on the page, besides the hero, it still shows. It only shows in some resolutions. Chrome inspector doesn't show anything out of ordinary, and the HTML+CSS is the same for the other pages, where it doesn't show up. Anyone have any ideas on this one?

[image: White sliver on left side of background image]

Here's the CSS:

```
#top {
    background: url('/www/images/heros/features/features_768_1x.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;

    @media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
        background: url('/www/images/heros/features/features_375_1x.png') no-repeat center center;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1366px) {
        background: url('/www/images/heros/features/features_768_1x.png') no-repeat center center;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 1366px) {
        background: url('/www/images/heros/features/features_1366_1x.png') no-repeat center center;
        background-size: cover;
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fngbqyq1/

**Update:**
-issue was image had white in it / not cropped properly (damn designer) *eyeroll* :p

Comment: You should provide some code, or tell us the link of your website!

Comment: If you say "only at some resolutions", do you mean it happens while you are resizing the window? Maybe the browser just forgets to reflow the page sometimes (During resizing, it takes guesses at which reflows it can skip.) So, does pressing F5 after resizing help?

Comment: Code is dead simple: static height, width 100%; Nothing else... Seems to only happen at resolution < 1366px

Comment: Added background css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `background-size: 100% 100%;`

OR

`background-size: 100vw 100vh;`

OR Simply

`background-size: 100vw;`

Comment: May go with 100vw... works, not sure if the client will approve. 
Why does 'cover' not work? I thought its purpose was to cover the entire area...

Comment: The purpose is that only. I can only give proper answer only if I get a working code, fiddle or link to your website

Comment: Well, here ya go, replicated! https://jsfiddle.net/fngbqyq1/

Comment: This is the problem of your [Image](http://ryanweiss.net/test/features_768_1x.png) only. Open the image in browser. You can see some blank space in that. Crop it out :)
http://ryanweiss.net/test/features_768_1x.png

Comment: Oh my, man... sorry about that! Designer gave me bad asset. I checked dimensions but didn't actually look at the image. Late here, I need sleep :p. Ahhh, thank you!

Comment: @RyanWeiss Cool man. Sleep :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121057/discussion-between-syam-pillai-and-ryan-weiss).